# How to modify the source code of a war file with install4j?

Tags: install4j

My teammates and I, have an issue concerning the update or bug fixes in a delivered application to the client, each time we need to fix bugs, we have to make a trip to the client's company in order to make new modifications.
We proposed to create an executable update that will apply the patch automatically. The solution is set to be created with install4j.

In more details, the user must specify the war file's location, the installer will extract its content, add/replace the needed files, then re-archive it.

I want to know first if there is any alternative to that solution.
Secondly, I tried to run a simulation where I would specify to the installer a zip file's location, then extract it on a temporary folder, and overwrite it with the content added in the Files step of install4j, and finally rezip the file, but nothing happened.

Here is what I made in the installer configuration process:

- I created a file chooser in a configurable form screen that will return  the path of the zip file in a variable named `zipPath`.
- Then, I create a "Extract zip File" action where I set the zip file's name as java code :

```
Zip file : context.getVariable("zipPath");
```

and specified the temporary directory's path.

```
Destination directory : tempDir/temp
```

- Copy the files specified in the distribution tree to the temporary files.

```
Destination directory : tempDir/temp
```

```
Source files or directories : tempDir/needed files
```

where needed files is the folder in which the installer will copy the distribution tree files.

- Create a new zip file in the new temp folder.

```
ZIP file : tempDir/temp/Zipfile.zip
```

```
Source files or directories : tempDir/needed files
```

I don't know yet how to replace the zip file I want to exploit the variable returned by the file chooser to do so, but anyway I looked for the new created files and I don't seem to find them anywhere on my computer.

Is there something wrong with my configuration? Or is there a step that I skipped? Is there a good piece of documentation, or a straight forward example of what I am trying to do, as I find the official examples and documentation confusing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you set the zip file name to Java code, that only works in scripts, not in text fields. The variable replacement syntax in text fields works like this:

```
${installer:zipPath}
```

In general, to check what is happening, look at the `.install4j/installation.log` file in your installation directory. If you do not have an "Install files" action in your project, the log file will be in the temporary directory, but it will be deleted at the end of the installer.

You can add the argument

```
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=[path to log file]
```

to write the log file to any writable path and make sure it is not deleted.

In your scenario, it would make sense to delete the "Install files" action from the template and not use the distribution tree at all. Instead, ZIP your new files into a file named `patch.zip` and add them on the "Installer->Custom code & Resources" tab. Then you would need the following actions:

- "Extract a ZIP file" action for the file `${installer:sys.resourceDir}/patch.zip` to some temp directory
- "Extract a ZIP file" action for the file `${installer:zipPath}` to the same temp directory
- "Create a ZIP file" action for the file `${installer:zipPath}` using the same temp directory as the source

---

**Update 2018-01-12**

As of install4j 6.1, there is a "Modify ZIP file" action that can directly modify ZIP files, so the above sequence of actions is no longer necessary.

Comment: Well, I have figured out how to modify the zip file, and my mistake was indeed that I set the zip file name to Java code. Still, in the final project, I would have to extract the content of the war file and modify it, then repack it.

Comment: There is anyway, a new issue that I have found as I want to create a backup folder where I would extract the content of the war file.
For that I did an "Extract a ZIP File" action, in which I specified the following:
`ZIP file: ${installer:zipFile}`
`Destination directory: ${installer:sys.docsDir}\Mes Sauvegardes\${installer:backupName}`
backupName is a variable which returns the date of the creation of the folder and concatenate it with "backup".
The issue is that the zip doesn't get extracted and the folder isn't created.

Comment: Ok I figured what it was, and yet again it was a silly mistake , the date was printed with a colon, so I changed it and now, it works.